# ¿Por qué cada vez que actualizo mi página web ysubo los cambios al host, debo borrar caché y cookies para ver los cambios?

Tags: php, web, cookies, cache, host

Cada vez que hago cambios a mi página web en local y al subir los archivos al host, si ya he entrado previamente al link debo borrar cache y cookies para poder visualizar los cambios. A qué se debe esto?

Comment: Los navegadores guardan los archivos en el caché con la finalidad de que el usuario que lo usa pueda ver dichos archivos aun así esté offline, esto con la finalidad de hacer menos peticiones al servidor de destino y evitar posteriores inconvenientes de carga. [Si investigas un poco más, te darás cuenta de que puedes desactivar el caché en tu sitio con htaccess](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/apache-web-server/turning-off-caching-using-htaccess). Adicionalmente, no es necesario borrar las cookies.

Answer (score 0):

En el siguiente [enlace](https://www.ttandem.com/blog/la-cache-y-por-que-no-veo-actualizado-mi-sitio-web/) se explica, en mayor o menor medida, como la caché afecta al momento de realizar cambios en una pagina web y poder visualizar los cambios, talvez encuentres la respuesta a tu pregunta, pero básicamente lo esencial son los siguientes puntos:

1. A veces sucede que el navegador utiliza un fichero local, en el 'caché', aunque en el sitio web exista una versión más reciente del mismo fichero, y por tanto no vemos la página actualizada. En estos casos se puede indicar al navegador que ignore los ficheros que tiene almacenados localmente y vuelva a solicitar todos los elementos de una página web. Se puede forzar la carga completa de una página web utilizando estas combinaciones de teclas según el navegador y el sistema operativo
2. Otras veces el 'culpable' de que no se vean los cambios en el sitio web no es el navegador. Puede suceder que entre nuestro navegador e internet haya un ordenador que hace de intermediario (un servidor proxy caché). El objetivo detrás del uso de estos equipos intermediarios es similar al "caché" de nuestro navegador: las empresas suelen minimizar el tráfico de internet utilizando un 'proxy caché'.
3. El problema puede surgir si entre el momento en que el "proxy caché" almacenó la página web en su primera solicitud y una siguiente vez en que se solicita la misma página ésta ha sido modificada. Para el  "proxy caché" la página todavía podría estar dentro de su vida útil y en vez de recoger la página web de internet devolverá al navegador una versión obsoleta de la página guardada localmente.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/255376)

Comment: @Israel-ICM gracias por la observación, ya se ha corregido la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

como bien dijeron todos los navegadores guardan cache de esta manera se evita que se envíen peticiones constantes al servidor y así también el sitio carga mas rápido. Puedes forzar a que el navegador de la persona que esta visitando tu sitio no almacene el caché añadiendo estas líneas de código dentro de las etiquetas **HEAD**

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0"> 
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Saludos!

PD: No es necesario borrar las cookies de tu navegador, solo el caché para que se puedan reflejar los cambios que haz hecho en tu sitio.